# It is possible to remove the product qty field?

Tags: product, custom, magento2.3.3, remove

I want to remove the 'Qty' field without removing the 'add to cart' button. But the best I've found is:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true" />
```

Which removes both fields. Any suggestion to avoid this? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: How about adding some CSS `.field.qty {display: none;}` that hides it?

Comment: Your solution make sense, but for some reason it doesn't work. I replaced the line in '/var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_module.less'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for remove only quantity box you must override addtocart.phtml file. follow the below link.

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-remove-quantity-box-on-product-details-page.html

Comment: The code to remve from the file is a bit different in magento 2.3.3 but it's easy enough to figure out to accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLopez